# How to validate a form in liferay6.1 using jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, liferay-6

i have a form with Booktitle,Author.I need to validate these two fields like if any one of them is empty it should display the message as field is mandatory.How can i achieve this.I have searched in google for this,and modified the code like below.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#_fm").validate();
        var element = document.getElementById("_bookTitle");
        element.className = element.className + " required";
        element = document.getElementById("_author");
        element.className = element.className + " required";
    });
</script>
<aui:form name="fm" method="POST" action="<%=updateBookURL.toString()%>">
    <aui:input name="bookTitle" label="Book Title" />
    <aui:input name="author" />
    <aui:button type="submit" value="Save" />
</aui:form>
```

and the portlet.xml is :

```
<portlet>
        <portlet-name>libraryportlet</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <instanceable>false</instanceable>
        <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
        <header-portlet-javascript>https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js</header-portlet-javascript>
        <header-portlet-javascript>https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js</header-portlet-javascript>
        <header-portlet-javascript>
            http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js
        </header-portlet-javascript>
        <footer-portlet-javascript>
            /js/main.js
        </footer-portlet-javascript>

        <css-class-wrapper>libraryportlet-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
    </portlet>
```

But no success.Where i am doing wrong.Can anyone tell me.Thank you.

Comment: I advice you to not use jquery/javascript for validation. Javascript runs clientside and is easy to disable.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your form by using liferay's own Alloy validator, which eliminates the need to use jquery and jquery validate for form validation.

First, you need to import the validator class into your jsp:

```
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.Validator" %>
```

And then you can go on to define the rules for each of your input fields:

```
<aui:form name="fm" method="POST" action="<%=updateBookURL.toString()%>">
    <aui:input name="bookTitle" label="Book Title">
        <aui:validator name="required"  />
    </aui:input>

    <aui:input name="author">
        <aui:validator name="required"  />
    </aui:input>

    <aui:button type="submit" value="Save" />
</aui:form>
```

This prevents the form from being submitted if any of the fields are empty. As Bondye said, you may also want to do some server-side validation since Alloy runs on top of Javascript which can be easily disabled by the user, thus exposing your application to some unhandled exception in case an empty form is submitted.